# Differences between these four branches of physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, terminology, statics

1. I am wondering what are the main differences between these four branches of physics: Statics, Kinematics, Dynamics, and Kinetics?
2. And whether the following relationships are correct or not?

   - Statics: there is **no speed** and there is **no acceleration**
   - Kinematics: there is **speed** and there is **no acceleration**
   - Dynamics: there is **speed** and there is **acceleration**
   - Kinetics: there is **speed** and there is **acceleration**

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1135/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27897/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I still can not see the difference between DYNAMICS and KINETICS?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Please do not use words in all capital letters. It is completely unnecessary and makes the text harder to read. Also please note that any time you write a question with a numbered list, that is almost certainly indicating that the post should be broken into several more focused posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple Google search helps out. See this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematics) and its menu in the right side. This questions is all about definitions of words:

- **Statics**: When the object is not accelerating and *moving with* (standing still on / in equilibrium with) its surroundings. The requirements are Newton's 1st law:

$$\sum \vec F=0 \qquad \sum\vec\tau=0$$

- **Kinematics**: The study of motion.
- **Dynamics** and **kinetics**: The study of the *causes* of (changes in) motion. That would be *forces* and *torques* etc. Newton's 2nd law tells the connection: $$\sum \vec F=m\vec a\qquad \sum \vec \tau=m\vec \alpha$$ The word *dynamics* took over more and more over the past 100 years, but as far as I'm aware the two words are used interchangeably depending on the field of science.