# Correct terminology for combined kinematic and dynamic state

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, soft-question, kinematics, terminology

The *kinematic* state is defined as the position and orientation in space. The *dynamic* state is defined as the associated velocities.

What is the correct terminology for the combined kinematic and dynamic state? Can I call it the *kinetic* state?

Answer (score 3):

The *kinematic* state involves all positions, velocities, accelerations, and orientations.

The *kineto-static* state involves the kinematics plus all inertial and applied forces.

The *dynamic* state is the integration of the *kineto-static* state over time.

See my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/1144/392) relating to the terminology.

Comment: How is there any difference between dynamic and kinematic state according to your definitions?

Comment: The kinematic state has no description for forces. It is simply a relationship of positions and orientations and their derivatives. Dynamic state involves solving for all the forces in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Two  particles at a given position, one moving and the other at rest are having the same kinematic state. But dynamic state takes in the velocity. When you need to specify both position and velocity - it becomes kinetic state. After all kinematics + dynamics = Kinetics.

Comment: I think kinematic state involves derivatives as well. Dynamics = kinematics + forces/torques. @ja72's answer seems more correct.

Answer (score -1):

After all kinematics + dynamics = Kinetics.

I agree wholeheartedly.  Kinematics is a study of positions, velocities, accelerations, and orientations.  In the F=MA and therefore, A=F/M, doesn't the A- accelerations include the implied force and mass required?

Please another stupid word for someone who doesn't understand physics equations?