# Kinematics and dynamics - what pattern do they portray?

Tags: kinematics, terminology

The Equations which are derived for kinematics and dynamics are some patterns related to the body in motion.

What is the demarcation in the pattern that kinematic equations and dynamic equations help us to see?

What is the difference in the prediction of motion made by kinematic equations and dynamic equations?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1135/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit please, maybe with some examples that highlight your problem?