# Dynamics and kinematics of quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, kinematics, terminology, hilbert-space

What is the difference between [dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamics_%28mechanics%29) and [kinematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematics) of quantum field theory? I read that in QFT there is no possibility to keep the two things distinct because of a problem with the separability of the Hilbert space on which the theory is defined. So, I would like to know if they are associated to a particular kind of transformation that has to satisfy some constraints.

Comment: More on kinematics and dynamics: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1135/2451 and links therein.

Comment: "Dynamics" and "Kinematics" are classical mechanical terms (and are arbitrary even there). It doesn't make much sense to me to try and apply them to quantum theory (field or not).